# Invalid compressed data in zip

Tags: c++, zip, compression

So as a class project I was trying to build a simple archive cracker. I was simply calling `unzip` through the shell (using `popen`) and iterating over a dynamically generated list of words.

Anyways, I setup a test archive with the password "hunter". Now I checked my program with easier passwords and I know it works. However for a lot of "long" passwords, the utility gives a weird error. So I tried, in the case of the above-mentioned archive, manually entering the following passwords:

- "pass" - The password dialog reopened, indicating that it was an incorrect password.
- "hunter" - The contents of the zip were decompressed in the target forlder.
- "dacbe" - I get the error saying "Unable to expand test.zip into "Project" (Error 2 - No such file or directory) or if done via terminal, "Invalid compressed data to inflate".

So I thought maybe it was the utility at fault somehow I switched to Unarchiver, same issue with the same password string. Switched a different third party utility, same issue with the error being "Error on decrunching".

Why is this happening for certain passwords?

I am running macOS 10.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unzip has a deliberately weak filter on an entered password to check it for validity. Only one byte of decrypted data is checked, so there is a 1/256 chance of a random password passing that check and proceeding to decompress. As you have discovered, in that case the decompression will soon thereafter detect an erroneous password.